# How can I embed an initialized variable in a struct?

Tags: go

Is there a good way to embed initialized struct variables in another struct?

Consider the following situation:

```
type Account struct {
  AdminUser, AdminPass string
}

const (
  acc1: "account_user",
  pass: "111222"
)

var AccountDef = Account {
  AdminUser: "acc1",
  AdminPass: "pass1"
}

type Login struct {
  Acc *AccountDef
  Username, Password, Token string
}

var LoginDef = Login {
  Token: "adaasdasddas1123"
}
```

I want to reuse `AccountDef` in `Login`, then I want to instantiate `LoginDef` in another function then use it for rendering templates like `LoginDef.Acc.AdminUser`

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to follow what you're trying to ask. Perhaps I'm tired, or perhaps you didn't explain very well. Could you please rewrite it more clearly?

Comment: [Embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) has a specific meaning in Go, but I don't see you using embedded structs here at all. Are you trying to use them in this way?

Comment: @JimB yes. I'm trying to use them in this way so that I can use initialized AccountDef in Login struct so when I instantiate in a function with `new(Login)` or `Login{}` I want `AdminUser` and `AdminPass` both filled in with default values so that I don't have to use `Login{AdminUser: "acc1", AdminPass: "pass1"}` for each and every function that requires it. I could look at using another private function to do this job and call it but was wondering if there's a better way than just creating a factory function

Comment: This really sounds like some sort of config file with the admin credentials that you load each time you need to use them. I get a bit ichy with these strings in source code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `Login` to contain the fields from an `Account`, you can embed them like so:

http://play.golang.org/p/4DXnIsILd6

```
type Account struct {
    AdminUser string
    AdminPass string
}

type Login struct {
    *Account
    Username, Password, Token string
}

func main() {
    acct := &Account{
        AdminUser: "username",
        AdminPass: "pass",
    }

    login := Login{Account: acct}

    fmt.Println("login.AdminUser:", login.AdminUser)
    fmt.Println("login.AdminPass:", login.AdminPass)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but what I'm looking for is not instantiating default values in every function. I am instantiating for instance in your example's case, `Account` about 20-30 times. I want to have a reference to constructor instead

Comment: So you want to re-use an `Account` with certain values, instead if initializing new ones? If that's the case, just make a single `Account` in a scope that makes sense. I'm not sure what the question is now, or what this has to do with embedding. Maybe try creating an example showing exactly what you want to happen.